# What does setting an array equal to [-1]*n mean in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm reading some python code and I came across a line of code that says `arr = [-1]*n` where arr is an array and n is an integer. What does this notation mean? What would arr look like after this?

I feel bad asking this question here, because it feels more like a question for google, but I can't find anything on google by just googling the line of code, and I don't know the name of the notation.

Comment: _"What would arr look like after this?"_ It would look like `print(arr)`.

Comment: You could just try it out in the interactive interpreter

Comment: I'd suggest you to use python console for simple statements like this one

Comment: Have you tried running it to see what happens?

Comment: Multiplying a number by n is the same as adding the number to itself n times. The same thing happens with lists: `[-1] * n` is like `[-1] + [-1] + [-1] ...`.

Comment: Wow, I feel silly. Why didn't I think of running it for myself??? I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: BTW, in Python these are called lists, not arrays.

Answer (score 3):

It means, that the resulting array will be that cell repeated `n` times. In other words it will return an array with `n` elements when the initial array had one element. Every one of them will be `-1` in this case.

In general it will produce an array repeated n-times, for example `[1, 2, 3] * 2 == [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: One point of clarification: your answer seems to be implying that the result will always have length `n`.  Could you update your answer to make clear that, for example `[1, 2] * 2 == [1, 2, 1, 2]`?

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = ['z', 'r', 't']
n = 5
arr = [-1] * n
print arr

'''
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
'''

# the values of 'arr' have been changed
```

Comment: Even if `arr = []` the answer would still be `[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]`